# Eclipse suddenly stopped running code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I opened up a file from yesterday which ran just fine, and now eclipse won't run my code. When I click run, it displays an option for two different ant builds, either of which it will run. I do not know why it stopped working all of the sudden.... help??

Comment: Elaborate your problem and add more details

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me when I dragged a file into the editor, without storing it into a Java project. So to solve this, put the `.java` file in a *Java Project*:

```
File > New > Project > Java > Java Project
```

finally drag the file into that project (in the *Project Explorer*), not the editor.